# making value of start_time in timepicki variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make start time in timepicki as shown below , it's not working it gives me another value not as $(".add-time").val().

```
<input type="text" name="time" value="{{admission.time}}" class="timepicker add-time form-control required"> 

$('.add-time').timepicki({start_time: $(".add-time").val()});
```

Comment: If you want to get some help you need to be more specific. Please post a working example of your code, some debug information or anything we can work with. For starters you could provide the value of your $(".add-time").val() and the actual result that you get.

Comment: plz look again , the  value of {{admission.time}} as ex. 12:00 in the timepicker it shows another value 3:54  @K. Kirsz

Comment: The start time option must have this array format:["06", "00", "AM"] Check the {{admission.time}} value. What is the output of this;

Comment: it's a string of 12:00 @liontass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split() the val() of the input.The array result plus one element ("AM") its the value of the start_time option.Try the following JQuery code:

```js
var time=$(".add-time").val();
time=time.split(":");
time.push("AM");
$('.add-time').timepicki({start_time: time});
```